# How to use web chat interface of MS Botframework for DialogFlow bot

Tags: botframework, chatbot, dialogflow-es

I have a dialogflow agent, it is currently integrated with slack. However I want to use the web chat interface provided by MS BotFramework.
I have tried to find but could not find any documentation for this.

Comment: You may start by reading this: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat

Answer (score 1):

[Webchat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-webchat?view=azure-bot-service-3.0) channel is enabled by default and the way to see it is :

1. Open your bot in the Azure Portal and click **Channels** blade.
2. Click **Edit** for the **Web Chat** channel
3. Under **Secret keys**, click **Show** for the first key
   [image]
4. Copy the **Secret key** and the **Embed code**.
5. Click **Done**

So the embed code is actually an iframe which you can place in your website or share with others who want to use your bot. Or you can use the `src` of the iFrame too to reach the bot directly.

In case [webchat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-webchat?view=azure-bot-service-3.0) is disabled , you can enable it back by unchecking the `disable` checkbox in webchat.

[image]

To gain more in-depth understanding of webchat, as Nicolas mentioned, start having a look at https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat

Comment: thanks for the details, but how would i use dialogflow as a backend nlp engine with this?